# Non Linear Recursive / Online Least Squares

Tags: least-squares, non-linear, online-processing

I am searching for a recursive or online non linear least squares algorithm. I want to spread the computation out as new data is sampled like in the linear Recursive Least Squares or the LMS.

Ideally a recursive Levenberg–Marquardt algorithim would exist as Levenberg–Marquardt works great on my non linear problem but need to reuse all the samples to calculate a new estimate.

The online recursive non linear estimators I have found so far are:

- The Extended Kalman Filter
- Unscented Kalman Filter
- Particle filter

Some articles I have found interesting:

- Two step estimator as described in the paper "Optimal recursive iterative algorithm for discrete nonlinear least-squares estimation (1996)" by Gordon T. Haupt, N. J. Kasdin, George M. Keiser, and Bradford W. Parkinson
- The Modified Extend Kalman Filter as described in the paper "A recursive algorithm for nonlinear least-squares problems (2007)" by A. Alessandri, M. Cuneo, S. Pagnan, M. Sanguineti

Do other online non linear estimators exist?
What are the popular online non linear estimators? I have minimal experience with non linear estimation.

Comment: it is not a good idea to place particle filter in the same category as the "modified" kalman ones, since they are based on linearization

Comment: @Fat32, The Unscented Kalman Filter (UKF) doesn't linearize the problem.